# Using Angular $resource, Fetch data on button click not working

Tags: angularjs

I am using angularjs ngresource to fetch a list of data from database on button click. But when i click button nothing happens. What i am doing wrong.

app.js

```
'use strict';
var App = angular.module('app',['ngResource']);
```

graph_service.js

```
'use strict';
App.factory('Graph', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource(
            'http://localhost:8080/SPsystem/stats' 
        );
}]);
```

graph_controller.js

```
'use strict';
App.controller('GraphController', ['$scope', 'Graph', function($scope, Graph) {
          var self = this;
          self.graph= new Graph();

          self.graphs=[];

          self.fetchAllstats = function(){
              self.graphs = Graph.query();

          }
      }]);
```

minimal html

```
<body ng-app="app" class="ng-cloak">
<div class="generic-container" ng-controller="GraphController as ctrl">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div>      
      <input type="button" ng-click="fetchAllstats()" value="Fetch" class="btn btn-success">
    </div>           

    <div class="panel-heading"><span class="lead">List</span></div>
    <div class="tablecontainer">
      <table class="table table-hover">
       <thead>
        <tr>
         <th>x</th>
         <th>y</th>
         <th width="20%"></th>
          </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="g in ctrl.graphs">
      <td>{{g.x}}</td>
      <td>{{g.y}}</td>   
         </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>             
     </div>
     </div>       
 </div>
 </div> 
</body>
```

Comment: show the module declaration

Comment: Please check now, i have added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a method named query in your factory,

Change your factory like this,

```
App.factory('Graph', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
  {
    // Resource object 
    var resource = $resource('http://localhost:8080/SPsystem/stats');      
      /* Custom function to retrieve a issue list*/
    resource.query= function () {
        return this.query()      
    };       
    return resource;
  })
```

Comment: @sajeethran still nothing happens

Comment: @user3844782 can i get teamviewer?

Comment: @user3844782 ok np :)